# Need to offer free shipping on a configurable product

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, shipping

We are using Magento Community 1.7.0.2. Here is our situation that we need help:

1) We offer products for sale, which can be purchased in “each” quantity or in the “case” quantity.

2) This product is setup as a configurable product, where the “each” option is a simple product and the “case” option is a separate simple product.

3) I want to offer free shipping for the “case” quantity simple product.

4) I created a category that is called “Case quantity items that should receive free shipping”. I set this to ACTIVE, but not in navigation.

5) I add the desired Case quantity simple product to the category specified in item #4 above.

6) I then create a shopping cart price rule. In this rule, I set free shipping to matching items online. I set actions to be “Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions if all of these conditions are true”, and I set it to read category = 123 (where category 123 is the same as item #4 above).

Can someone please help me get this setup properly so that I can set a simple product, assigned to a configurable product, to allow free shipping???

Comment: If the rule appears set up correctly, try opening the product in the backend and simply saving it (without modification). Also make sure to reindex.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this on a Demo Store and it seems no problem to have free shipping for only one simple child product under a configurable product. So most probably it's in the configuration of your shopping cart price rule.

I created a shopping cart price rule to apply free shipping to 'nine_3' which is a child product of the configurable 'nine'. I added the 'nine_3' product to a newly created 'Free shipping' category which has id 36.

This is my **conditions** tab:
[image: Conditions tab]

And the **actions** tab:
[image: Actions tab]

Now, if I go to the 'nine' product detail page ('Nine West Women's Lucero Pump') and add size 3 to my shopping cart, free shipping will be applied. If I edit the shopping cart item and choose another size, the regular shipping charges apply.